# What are docpad environment defaults / how to configure

Tags: docpad

Cannot find any information on the defaults/configs for environment. Actualy I want an own generate --env myenv without minification of the html output as  --env development does.

Comment: Minification of output is not a property of the environment. It is usually a task that runs in the docpad.coffee file. Which skeleton are you using? The config options for docpad are found at: http://docpad.org/docs/config

Comment: well, but in the config I do not find any minification task adressed. By default it is set differently for development and static. But do not know how to adress that. Have a very bare docpad.coffe with almost no definitions.

Comment: I've expanded what I mean in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the jade-plugin-files. So you need this in your docpad.coffee:

```
environments:
  static:
    plugins:
      jade:
        jadeOptions: 
          pretty: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way this is done is by running a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task in the `writeAfter` event at the bottom of the docpad.coffee file. If you download the skeleton [HTML5 boilerplate with grunt](https://github.com/lukekarrys/html5-boilerplate.docpad) then this will be easier to see. Its the second one on the list when you install skeletons through docpad.

What is often done in order to display different style files (eg minified or original) depending on the environment is to place some code in a layout which queries the environment and depending on that, output the corresponding files. Perhaps like this:

```
<%if @site.env == 'development':%>
   <%- @getBlock('styles').add(@site.styles).toHTML() %>
<%else:%>
   <link  rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/all.min.css" />
<%end%>
```

You could do the above without grunt, of course, if you already have the minified and unminified files. Grunt just does the minification and combining each time docpad regenerates.

What the HTML5 skeleton does is use a helper function and a grunt config file to achieve the same:

```
    getGruntedStyles: ->
            _ = require 'underscore'
            styles = []
            gruntConfig = require('./grunt-config.json')
            _.each gruntConfig, (value, key) ->
                styles = styles.concat _.flatten _.pluck value, 'dest'
            styles = _.filter styles, (value) ->
                return value.indexOf('.min.css') > -1
            _.map styles, (value) ->
                return value.replace 'out', ''
```

If you really want to define your own environment it can be as simple as defining a value for the `env` property in the docpad.coffee file and then query for that value in the layout.

In docpad.coffee

```
    env: myenvironment
```

And in the layout:

```
<%if @site.env == 'myenvironment':%>
```

Comment: maybe I was unclear. I did not mean css minification but simple html minification or compression. Actually I had a look on html5 boilerplat with grunt. But, to be honest, I do not realy understand right the part about the gruntedStyles you mention. I reduced all scripts to a minimum and to my effords. I do call a grunt routine with the writeafter, and one task is uncss. But uncss fails if the html is minified/compressed. And with my own environment, that I call, all html is flat. Therefor I want to configure an environment with prettyfied html output as --env development does.

Comment: In that context I do run into another conflict, that also the html5boilerplategrunt template does not solve. Maybe you have also some ideas on [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934061/docpad-grunt-iteration-over-all-html-files)

Comment: @user1308302 Yes - the gruntedStyles is a bit hard to follow, but the simpler way is using the "if" statement in the layout - which the html5 skeleton used to do. I suspect from what you are saying that whatever process you are using to 'flatten' the html there is something in that process making a decision about the environment it is in.

Comment: I assumed it was a default setting from docpad in the static env. But now I think it has to do with jade to which I switched fom eco. In static (and all custom) env eco renderes normal html, jade renders flatt. In develompment env both render expanded. Thats somehow weird. I cannot find where these settings are.