# docpad grunt iteration over all html files

Tags: gruntjs, docpad

I am using the docpad-plugin-grunt with several grunt tasks. I wonder what is the best way to run tasks over all docpad generated html documents without individual files to be specified in the gruntfile.js. Is there a routine where docpads handing over to grunt all filenames? Can dopad handle the iteration or is a seperated script needed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think grunt is the way to go for this, what you really want to do is hook in to the rendering process that docpad does for each document. Typically, grunt is used to run a task at the end of the generation to do something that docpad doesn't do out of the box.

To intercept docpad's rendering process you probably want to handle the [docpad render event](http://docpad.org/docs/events) which you define in the events section of the docpad.coffee file.

Assuming you want to minify your html you might do something like this (more or less lifted from the docpad documentation):

```
render: (opts) ->
    # Prepare
    {inExtension,outExtension,templateData,file,content} = opts
    docpad = @docpad

    # Render if applicable
    if outExtension in ['html']
        opts.content = minifyFunction(content)
```

Comment: ah, that looks promising. Where to find docs about all possible opts? I'd like to setup a process with uncss and premailer over each html document. I think, it will need a plugin. Do you know any good tut about writing plugins for docpad?

Comment: @user1308302 glad this has helped. If it has been of use please do a plus on the answer. The official docs are not clear about the options passed. You don't need to write a plugin. You can do it all from within the docpad.coffee file. However, in the long term it would make sense to extract your code to a plugin.

Comment: How would I pass over the content to a grunt task?